# Vanilla Js: Start a while loop in one event, break it with a second event? ('mouseover' start, 'mouseout' sets loop condition to false)

Tags: javascript, while-loop, dom-events, mouseevent

I'd like to repeat an animation that begins in a `'mouseover'` event until a `'mouseout'` event is triggered. I've tried wrapping the `'mouseover'` action in a while loop after giving its condition global scope, then setting its condition to `false` in the `'mouseout'` callback, but the while loop doesn't break. I tried assigning the `'mouseout'` both outside and inside of the while loop, with the same result.

Is there an event-driven way to break a while loop that had begun in another event's callback? I'm curious about this question in general, and specifically, how to apply a solution to the context of `'mouseover'` and `'mouseout'` events. Thanks!

Also: The snippet below works as-is. I commented out the faulty while loop logic. The animation should, if it worked as I wanted, keep radiating out gold rings from the same center on a Google Map, till the `mouseout` occurs. Minus the while loop, it works, but only once.

```js
var haloRad = 1;
var center = {lat:20.0000,lng:20.0000};
var hrefHalo = new google.maps.Circle({
  'strokeColor'  : 'RGB(255,255,100)',
  'strokeOpacity': 1,
  'strokeWeight' : 3,
  'fillColor'    : 'RGB(255,255,100)',
  'fillOpacity'  : 0, 
  'map'          : null,
  'center'       : center,
  'radius'       : haloRad,
});
// var isOver;

a.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  // isOver = true;
  hrefHalo.setMap(map); 
  // while(isOver){
       var i = 1;     
       for (; i <= 10; i++){
          (function animateHalo(i){
             setTimeout(function(){
                hrefHalo.setRadius(haloRad * (1 + (i / 10)));
             }, i * 75)
          })(i)
        }
  // }
});

a.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  // isOver = false;
  hrefHalo.setMap(null);
});
```

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. Once your mouse over function begins, it has to finish before any other event handlers can be called. So you can't break a while loop from some other part of the code. You need to make each iteration asynchronous, e.g. by using a setTimeout-based pseudo-loop instead of a while loop.

Comment: Cool -- but isn't that what I already did, with the setTimeout closure in my for loop? Or do you mean, set the limiting condition of "i" to be really big with the code that I have, then have the mouseout event call a clearTimeout (assuming I set a timer variable outside the scope of both event listeners)? But that still seems problematic to me. If it's single threaded and needs to complete that event before others can be called, making "i" very large will tie up the thread, right? Sorry if this is worded poorly/is missing an obvious point. It's new territory for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created two different ways you can do this.

1. Using JavaScript and the "hackish" way of canceling `setInterval`
2. Using Jquery and `animate` and its `stop()` function.

This fiddle shows both in action. Implement either into your code, I do not have you HTML or CSS to replicate your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/6oL7xg5n/2/

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    var h = $(".orange").height();
    myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("hllo");
    $(".orange").height(h);
        h++;
    }, 30);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}

$(".orange").on("mouseover", function() {
    myFunction();
});

$(".orange").on("mouseout", function() {
    myStopFunction();
});
// Jquery version
$(".apple").on("mouseover", function() {
    // Used "1000px" but you can use a different value or a variable
    $(this).animate({height: "1000px"}, 8000);
});

$(".apple").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).stop();
});
```